# use jquery to find any character and remove it

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, find, character

I have a website in drupal. There is seems to problem with it. Before the end of body tag  a digit appears 9. So I need to remove that through jQuery.

I know there is find() method in jQuery but is finds only the element not the character. I need to find character and remove it. It doesn't comes under any element than body tag so I cannot select element surrounds it and remove it.

```
<body>all the other site elements....9</body>
```

I need to remove that 9. Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: Why not remove it from the source. This is certainly not the right approach.

Comment: If you _need_ to do it client-side, it would be easier to do it in plain javascript, without jQuery. Select the last text node and remove the last character of its `textContent`.

Comment: No,no,no! You have rogue characters coming from the serverside, you don't use javascript to remove those !!!

Comment: Please advice how to remove that? I found only this solution to remove it from jQuery. There is no php file from where it is coming from. If it was I directly removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the reason that character is appended, and remove that. However, to do it client-side as a temporary fix:

You don't want to manipulate `innerHTML` (or `.html()`) of the entire document. Instead, grab the last child node of `document.body` (so far, jQuery can do that), verify it's a text node (jQuery falls short at this point), and shorten its text content a little. Neither `textContent` and `innerText` are cross-browser compatible ([though we might hope for `innerText` to become standard](http://www.davidtong.me/innerhtml-innertext-textcontent-html-and-text/)). However, for text nodes, `nodeValue` is available:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var node = document.body.lastChild;
  if(node && node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE){
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/9^/,"")
  }
})
```

Note the nine is assumed to be the *last* thing that appears in the body, and there is no invisible content following (whitespace, script tags, comment tags). Whitespace can be ignored by modifying the regex (left as an excercise for the reader), and skipping invisible nodes can de done via iteration (easier if tailored to your particular situation; it's a temporary fix after all).

Useful links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.lastChild
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.previousSibling

Comment: Thanks it worked very well. I changed the code little bit.    var node = document.body.lastChild;
   
  if(node && node.nodeValue == 9){
     
    node.nodeValue = "";
  }
Do you have any reference links from where I can learn these basic javascripting it is really very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @shreyas MDN (mozilla developer network) is a great reference and it has some tutorials too